# Power Automate: Turn Object Into Array

Tags: json, power-automate

I have an API output That Has a Dynamic Object.

example:

```
{
  "2024-01-10": "1",
  "2024-01-11": "1",
  "2024-01-12": "1"
}
```

I can get a String that looks like this:

```
{"2024-01-10":"1","2024-01-11":"1","2024-01-12":"1"}
```

But what I want is to be able to get output into a CSV or other sheet separating the 2

like this

| Date | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 2024-01-10 | 1 |
| 2024-01-11 | 1 |
| 2024-01-12 | 1 |

I have Tried About everything.

```
string(items('For_each')['dates'])
```

Then trying to split using

```
split(items('For_each')['dates'], ':')
```

i can't seem to separate it or at least turn the object into something else

Comment: You already asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using good old string replace.

Example input:

```json
{
  "2024-01-10": "1",
  "2024-01-11": "1",
  "2024-01-12": "1"
}
```

Example output:

```json
[
  {
    "date": "2024-01-10",
    "amount": "1"
  },
  {
    "date": "2024-01-11",
    "amount": "1"
  },
  {
    "date": "2024-01-12",
    "amount": "1"
  }
]
```

Power Automate expression used:

```js
json(
  replace(
  replace(
  replace(
  replace(
  replace(
    string(
      outputs('Compose')  // replace this with your variable/action/jsonProperty
    ),
  '{', '[{"date"|'),
  '}', '}]'),
  ',', '},{"date"|'),
  ':', ',"amount":'),
  '|', ':')
)
```